# How to add a certificate into a PDF file and check whether the pdf is not tampered externally?

Tags: c#, pdf, certificate, digital-signature, digital-certificate

I am working on some PDF related operations, and I need to check whether the PDF is not tampered by users or not. So I assume, that requires a digital signature to be added into the file. How to make sure that the pdf is not tampered?

I am using PDFSharp for PDF manipulation, and I don't think PDFSharp can do that but I am not sure. Is there any idea whether it can or not?

Comment: Asking explicitly for libraries can get your question closed/deleted in S.O, if there is a library, someone will tell you anyway. By the way what you need to add to the file is a digital signature, not a certificate.

Comment: Validation of PDF signatures can be done eg. with our SecureBlackbox or with iTextSharp (check the license!).

Comment: Read http://itextpdf.com/book/digitalsignatures for a comprehensive overview of digital signatures and PDF.

Comment: I got some code snippet for signing a PDF using iTextSharp, but that needs iTextSharp version > 5.x. And I need to use the LGPL version (4.1.6). And I hardly found any documentation for the version. Can you guys please help finding that?